# how to get last inserted id in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and try to add record in db. record is successfully inserted but now i need to getLast inserted id.

Insert record array here:

```
User::insert(
        [
            'first_name' => $data->first_name,
            'last_name'  => $data->last_name,
            'email'      => $data->signup_email,
            'contact'    => $data->signup_contact,
            'role_id'    => $data->role_id,
            'password'   => bcrypt($data->password_contact),
            'confirm_passsword'=>bcrypt($data->confirmpassword_contact),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d'),
        ]
    );
```

Thanks to all for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "insert" with "insertGetId". Thats it.